# Use short Urls within a public facing site

Tags: public-website, url-rewriting, internet-sites

My public SharePoint 2010 site has long (readable) Urls. Thats fine. But now we want to create some very short Urls for some specific campaigns. 
We want to use `www.ourdomain.nl/campaign1` and that has to show the same page as `www.ourdomain.com/businessunit/summer2012/seniorclasses/events/campaign1`

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely look into [URL Rewriting](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&site=webhp&q=url+rewrite+iis&oq=url+rewrite+iis&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.1576l5197l0l5449l5l5l0l0l0l1l184l534l3j2l5l0.llsin.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4af02922cf0b8eaf&ix=sea&ion=1&biw=1139&bih=999). It does exactly that.

Comment: Here's a link to the Microsoft IIS site introducing URL Rewriting: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Would it be possible to maintain these rewriting rules from within SharePoint?

Comment: Not directly, but I guess you could code something for it. You would need to be extra diligent though. A lot of it sits in the web.config, I'm not sure I would want end-users injecting stuff in there without proper checks

Comment: And what about this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415 ?